# The door **creaked open**

Tags: parts-of-speech

> The door **creaked open**.

1. Could you explain what part of speech is "open"? Adjective? If I understand right, "creacked" is a verb in the sentence. Is it idiomatic to use an adjective after this verb? On the internet I've read that typically we use an adjective after "be" or “sense” verbs. Obviously, "creaked" is not from that group of verbs.
2. What's the difference in its meaning between:

> The door **creaked open**.
>
> The door **opened with a creak**.

I don't see the difference in the meaning.

Comment: You don't see the difference in the meaning because there isn't one. Except that [***creaked open***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22creaked+open%22) is a slightly more poetic / literary usage.

Comment: Note that without the adverbial element *(**open**)*, the verb ***to creak*** used intransitively doesn't particularly imply a subject like a door or a floorboard actually *moving* much, if at all. Even a locked door can creak - especially in the context of high winds. But the transitive usage *([He creaked the door open](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he+creaked+the+door%22))* doesn't seem possible without an adverbial element specifically indicating movement *(**...open, ...shut, ...back and forth**)*.

Comment: _Open_ is an adjective, used as a resultative marker indicating the state resulting from the  noisy movement of the door. If you want to call it an adverb, go right ahead; there's not much difference in English, and parts of speech are like underwear; you can change them whenever you want.

Comment: Yes, an adjective functioning as a predicative adjunct. It entails "the door creaked"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Could you explain what part of speech is "open"?

In a comment, @John Lawler replied:

> Open is an adjective, used as a resultative marker indicating the state resulting from the noisy movement of the door.
> If you want to call it an adverb, go right ahead; there's not much difference in English, and parts of speech are like underwear; you can change them whenever you want.

##### What's the difference in its meaning between "The door creaked open." and "The door opened with a creak."?

In comments, @FumbleFingers replied:

> You don't see the difference in the meaning because there isn't one.
> Except that creaked open is a slightly more poetic / literary usage.

> Note that without the adverbial element (**open**), the verb **to creak** used intransitively doesn't particularly imply a subject like a door or a floorboard actually moving much, if at all.
> Even a locked door can creak - especially in the context of high winds.
> But the transitive usage (He creaked the door open) doesn't seem possible without an adverbial element specifically indicating movement (**...open, ...shut, ...back and forth**).